# MapInfo Bing Aerial resolution/scale

Tags: mapinfo, bing-maps, scale

I am using MapInfo to display some Bing aerial photos. It seems as if it is using the wrong scale of imagery - they look blurred, as if the image has been enlarged.

Is there a way to force it to use a larger scale of imagery and therefore get more detail?

Comment: what version of MapInfo are you using?

Comment: It may also have to do with image compression.  A number of WMS-style services I have used have compressed (usually by turning them into JPEGs) the original images.

Comment: Mapperz - I'm using 10.5. jvangeld - It doesn't look like that. It looks more like it's been resized than over-compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same with bing, and also with openstreetmap in MI10.5

it seems to depend on the width (not height) of the mapwindow

at certain discrete width's (around 384 pts or 820 pts for example) the image suddenly resets to a very sharp and very OK display,

while resizing the window, you see it degrade, until it suddenly jumps to ok again

wonder if it depends on screen resolution settings, and why these strange numbers (not multiples of 256 tile size) and not dependent on height (any height is ok)

Comment: Well, it's hardly ideal but this does seem to work. Thanks!